# Check for duplicate entries into a mySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have this table structure:

```
|------------|--------------|---------------|---------------|
| LAN_Id     | LAN_Type     | LAN_fr-CA     | LAN_en-CA     |
|------------|--------------|---------------|---------------|
| 1          | Web          | Bonjour       | Hello         |
| 2          | Web          | Merci         | Thanks        |
| 3          | Web          | Merci         | Thanks        |
|------------|--------------|---------------|---------------|
```

How can I search for the duplicate entry ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL Duplicate entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964701/mysql-duplicate-entries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select min(lan_id), lan_type, `lan_fr-ca`, `lan_en-ca`, count(*)
from your_table
group by lan_type, `lan_fr-ca`, `lan_en-ca`
having count(*) > 1
```